# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: rampart

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat, rampart

I have made a web service using rampart-1.6.4 and axis2-1.6.4. I am able to run this on eclipse as I have successfully integrated axis and rampart.
Now, I need to run this as a web application.
I have made war file of axis2 using ant, and copied axis2.war into the "webapps" directory of Apache Tomcat.
rampart module is available in the list of loaded modules from the axis admin page (which is at http://localhost:8080/axis2/axis2-admin/listModules).

Check this ->[listmodules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcGO8.png)

Now running it on apache tomcat, it is showing error as :

**The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: rampart**

Below is the stacktrace :

[ERROR] The rampart-1.6.4.mar module, which is not valid, caused org.apache.rampart.Rampart
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.rampart.Rampart

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.rampart.Rampart
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.populateModule(ModuleBuilder.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.readModuleArchive(ArchiveReader.java:514)
    ... 87 more

Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: org.apache.rampart.Rampart
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.loadModuleClass(ModuleBuilder.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.populateModule(ModuleBuilder.java:121)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.rampart.Rampart
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleBuilder.loadModuleClass(ModuleBuilder.java:70)
    ... 89 more

I faced this problem initially when I didn't copy jar files from rampart/lib/* to axis2 lib folder.
I am not able to find solution for above.
Please see to it once.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added rampart.mar and rahas.mar in modules folder?
 If not add it first. Also you need to add `<module="rampart"/>` in axis2.xml.

Comment: Yes. I have added <module="rampart"/> in axis2.xml and it worked for me. 
Thanks